# How to add photos to an iPhone (without removing old synced photos)?

Tags: windows, macos, iphone

Assuming I do not want to use iCloud or I have very slow internet speed during my travel, I want to sync photos to my iPhone from my laptop but I don't want to lose the photos I already synced to my iPhone with my desktop, is there a way to do that? (Jailbreak methods count!)

Any OS. I have the following OS: OSX 10.9, 10.10, Windows 8.1, Windows 9.

Comment: Any OS. I have the following OS: OSX 10.9, 10.10, Windows 8.1, Windows 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound crazy but there really isn't a way to sync photos to your iOS devices without removing photos synced from an another computer - particularly because you have a slow internet connection.

- You may argue it's for a security or performance reason, but I personally think it's the laziness of Apple's engineers.

If you have a faster internet, however, you can download the images to your computer through softwares like TunesGo. :)

Let me know if you have more questions.